# Word wrap text in child div if it doesn't fit parent div width

Tags: html, css

```
<div class='jfmfs-friend' id='123'>
  <input type='checkbox'/>
  <img src='id.jpg'/>
  <div class='friend-name'>Himanshu Yadav</div>
</div>
```

I want to wrap text inside `friend-name` div.
I tried

```
div.friend-name  {
    margin-left: 10px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Here is the parent div css:

```
.jfmfs-friend {                
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    height:56px;
    margin:3px;
    padding:4px;
    width:176px;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;

}

.jfmfs-friend div {
    color:#111111;
    font-size:11px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I added all your code into the following jsbin.com example to show why it doesn't work for the example given.  I added a case where word wrapping will be exercised. You may check it out here:  http://jsbin.com/osopid/1 and the code here http://jsbin.com/osopid/2/edit

```
  <div class='jfmfs-friend' id='123'>
  <input type='checkbox' click='width()'/>
  <img src='id.jpg'/>
    <!-- 78px demonstrates no wrapping of the following div  -->  
    <div id='restrictedWidth' class='friend-name'>Himanshu Yadav</div>
    <div id='dbg'></div>
  </div>

  <div class='jfmfs-friend' id='123'>
  <input type='checkbox' click='width()'/>
  <img src='id.jpg'/>
    <!-- 164px demonstrates wrapping of the following div -->
    <div id='restrictedWidth2' class='friend-name'>Himanshu Yadav with more text proving that word wrap is working</div>
    <div id='dbg2'></div>
  </div>
```

Note the word-wrap added :

```
.jfmfs-friend {                
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    height:56px;
    margin:3px;
    padding:4px;
    width:176px;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;

}

.jfmfs-friend div {
    color:#111111;
    font-size:11px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}

div.friend-name  {
    margin-left: 10px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Added some jquery to print out the widths, so that we may inspect when an item should wrap:

```
$('#dbg').html('<div>'+$('#restrictedWidth').css('width')+'</div>');

$('#dbg2').html('<div>'+$('#restrictedWidth2').css('width')+'</div>');
```

I tested this all out in chrome, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`word-wrap`](http://www.css3.info/preview/word-wrap/) property introduced in CSS3. By using the `break-word` value should word wrap the text within the container.

Comment: I tried word-wrap property as word-wrap:break-work; but no luck.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav Could you elaborate a bit more as to what your trying to achieve? By using the `word-wrap` property when the parent container is not as wide as it's children, the text wraps around as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, though you may want to reconsider the height:

```
div.friend-name  {
    margin-left: 10px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

Comment: Given the styles that you have set it will not wrap until you place in more words or a longer word.  You may want to consider making the width smaller if you want wrapping for words as long as 78px (see my recent post and more importantly the live example @ http://jsbin.com/osopid/2/edit )